# How to plot, in R, a correlogram on top of a correlation matrix?

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I've followed the instructions on this website [from STHDA](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/correlation-matrix-a-quick-start-guide-to-analyze-format-and-visualize-a-correlation-matrix-using-r-software) to plot correlation matrices and correlograms in R. The website and examples are really good. However, I'd like to plot the upper part of the correlogram over the upper part of the correlation matrix.

Here's the code:

```
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.Correlation(mtcars, histogram=TRUE, pch=19)
```

This should give me the correlation matrix using scatter plots, together with the histogram, which I'd like to maintain. But for the upper part of the plot, I'd like to have the correlogram obtained from this code:

```
library(corrplot)
corrplot(cor(mtcars), type="upper", order="hclust", tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
```

The obvious way of doing it is exporting all graphs in pdf and then work with *Inkscape*, but it would be nicer if I could get this directly from R. Is there any possible way for doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Combining two specialty plots like that may be harder than just recreating it yourself. Check out `?pairs`, specifically looking at `lower.panel`, `diag.panel`, and `upper.panel`; it will let you recreate everything except the gradient colorbar on the right (which you can recreate in a myriad of ways).

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work nicely and easier indeed. However, I'm having issues in creating the circles as seen in corrplot (colour and size dependent on the correlation values) - as in, I'm just not getting them. And would legend() be one option for the gradient colourbar? Cheers!

Comment: Circles can be done "easily" with one of the `pch` characters within `text`, controlling its radius loosely with `cex`, but it's a little sloppy and inaccurate. I do not think there is an "automated" circle in base *R* graphics, and though some ancillary packages can do it for you, I often just resort to a couple of `polygon` or `line` calls and `sin`/`cos`, returning to the days of basic trigonometry. `legend` cannot do a colorbar like that.

Comment: If you search (Google as well as SO) for "*R* legend color gradient", you can find several working examples.

Comment: Hi, I've tried something in the line of:
`panel.cor <- function(w, z, ...)
{
    usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr));
    par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1));
    abs.r <- abs(cor(w, z));
    pts = seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100);
    xy = cbind(0.5 + abs.r * sin(pts), 0.5 + abs.r * cos(pts));
    SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(xy)), "polygon")));
}`
Unfortunately this doesn't work. To be honest, I'm not 100% familiar with functions in R. I think that this function is not working because it's not finding the centre of each graph, but I'm not sure. Would you mind giving some help? Cheers!

Comment: First, when clarifying your question (or after you tried something), especially when providing code, you really should edit your original question and post it there; it makes it much more readable. Second, when I say "easy", I never thought it would lead to `SpatialPolygons`, which are (in my opinion) considerably overkill here. (Why not just use `lines` and/or `polygon`?)

Comment: thanks for the info! Next time I`ll edit my question then! Living and learning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to using the panel functions within `pairs` is found in `help(pairs)`:

> A panel function should not attempt to start a new plot, but just plot within a given coordinate system: thus 'plot' and 'boxplot' are not panel functions.

So, you should use graphic-*adding* functions, such as `points`, `lines`, `polygon`, or perhaps (when available) `plot(..., add=TRUE)`, but not a straight-up plot. What you were suggesting in your comment (with `SpatialPolygons`) might have worked with some prodding if you actually tried to plot it on a device vice just returning it from your plotting function.

In my example below, I actually do "create a new plot", but I cheat (based on [this SO post](http://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-y-axis-in-a-r-plot/)) by adding a second plot on top of the one already there. I do this to shortcut an otherwise necessary scale/shift, which would still not be perfect since you appear to want a "perfect circle", something that can really only be guaranteed with `asp=1` (aspect ratio fixed at 1:1).

```
colorRange <- c('#69091e', '#e37f65', 'white', '#aed2e6', '#042f60')
## colorRamp() returns a function which takes as an argument a number
## on [0,1] and returns a color in the gradient in colorRange
myColorRampFunc <- colorRamp(colorRange)

panel.cor <- function(w, z, ...) {
    correlation <- cor(w, z)

    ## because the func needs [0,1] and cor gives [-1,1], we need to
    ## shift and scale it
    col <- rgb( myColorRampFunc( (1+correlation)/2 )/255 )

    ## square it to avoid visual bias due to "area vs diameter"
    radius <- sqrt(abs(correlation))
    radians <- seq(0, 2*pi, len=50)     # 50 is arbitrary
    x <- radius * cos(radians)
    y <- radius * sin(radians)
    ## make them full loops
    x <- c(x, tail(x,n=1))
    y <- c(y, tail(y,n=1))

    ## I trick the "don't create a new plot" thing by following the
    ## advice here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/multiple-y-axis-in-a-r-plot/
    ## This allows
    par(new=TRUE)
    plot(0, type='n', xlim=c(-1,1), ylim=c(-1,1), axes=FALSE, asp=1)
    polygon(x, y, border=col, col=col)
}

pairs(mtcars, upper.panel=panel.cor)
```

[image]

You can manipulate the size of the circles -- at the expense of unbiased visualization -- by playing with the radius. The colors I took directly from the page you linked to originally.

Similar functions can be used for your lower and diagonal panels.

Comment: That was great, thanks a lot for the help and the explanation!

Comment: See my edit, for correctly handling visual bias. Oops.